# fonts not working in pdf output with bookdown in RStudio

Tags: xetex, rstudio, bookdown

I am using bookdown in the Rstudio environment to produce a pdf book. This is running on Ubuntu 21.04, with the latest version of RStudio, R 4.0.4, and new installs of texlive and tinytex. I am using the ["Authoring Books and Technical Documents with R Markdown"](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/) by Yihui Xie as an example.

I would like to use some Truetype/Opentype fonts installed on my system. Therefore I am using XeLaTex and the fontspec package. But I only get the Computer Modern Font. Here is my "_output.yml" file:

```
bookdown::gitbook:
  css: style.css
  config:
    toc:
      before: |
        <li><a href="./">A Minimal Book Example</a></li>
      after: |
        <li><a href="https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown" target="blank">Published with bookdown</a></li>
    download: ["pdf", "epub"]
bookdown::pdf_book:
  latex_engine: xelatex
  includes:
    in_header: preamble.tex
  citation_package: natbib
  keep_tex: yes
  dev: "cairo_pdf"
  mainfont: Crimson Pro
  sansfont: Source Sans Pro
  monofont: Ubuntu Mono

bookdown::epub_book: default
```

And here is the preamble.tex file:

```
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{fontspec} % Font selection for XeLaTeX; see fontspec.pdf for documentation
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text} % to support TeX conventions like ``---''
\usepackage{xunicode} % Unicode support for LaTeX character names (accents, European chars, etc)
\usepackage{xltxtra} % Extra customizations for XeLaTeX

\setmainfont{Crimson Pro} % set the main body font (\textrm)
\setsansfont{Source Sans Pro}
\setmonofont{Ubuntu Mono}
```

This works fine with a regular LaTeX writing environment like TeXWorks or Gummi. But not in bookdown. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Two PDF files are being produced. One is in the book directory, the other is in subdirectory called "_book". The former has the computer modern font, the latter has the correct files. That's wierd, but ok ....